# GIT/VSO: Only share a subset of repo

Tags: git, azure-devops

In a Visual Studio solution I have several projects and I'm hosting everything through git in Visual Studio Online. I'm taking in a freelance developer and I only want him to get access to one of the projects.

What's a good way to achieve this? I really like to have him work through git as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could create multiple Git repositories in a Visual Studio Team Service Team Project. Permissions can be defined for each repository.

Using individual repositories for each projects has also other advantages, like eg. possibility to trigger builds on changes for each project individually.

You can add additional repositories and define permissions on the repositories in the code hub using the "Manage repositories" link or by calling the following url `https://yourtenant.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/yourproject/_admin/_versioncontrol`.